# Android: FlowLayout - break TextView at the end of the screen

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, flowlayout

I'm using in my app `FlowLayout` (https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout) and it has set horizontal orientation. When I have a long TextView I want to split this TextView into two `TextViews`. First TextView will be to the end of the screen and second TextView will start at the start of the second row.

Look at the screenshot (row 5):

[image: FlowLayout]

Do you have some idea how can I do it? Somehow easily :)

For info:

- main layout is LinearLayout (vertical orientation)
- and in the code I'm adding FlowLayout (each row)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one solution (maybe it's not the best):

create for every char own `TextView` component.